Can it be used if the dependent variable is a score?
I want to test if some variables influence a score. Before launching the following code, I tried with a normal linear regression but I saw that my distribution was characterized by heteroskedasticity, non-normality, but it was linear. My dataset is longitudinal.
My dependent variable is a score that goes from 0 to 100 (continuous) and then I have different independent variables that are percentage or dummy variables, for the mixed effects I used 'country' as factor.
I tried to use the function within the glmmTMB package:
glmmTMB(score ~ AN + BC + OU + AR + GE + LO +(1|COUNTRY), data = my_dataset)
So can I use this model or before doing this, do I have to check for GLMM diagnostic assumptions? If so, what should I do to be sure to use the correct model?
EDIT:
COMPANY COUNTRY   YEAR    score    AN     BC     OU   AR   GE    LO
Name1     UK      2018    55.5    33.33   25.4   1     0   22.5  14.1
Name1     UK      2019    48.2    40.00   28.2   1     1   28.5  17.4
Name2     France  2018    75.1    22.10   10.4   0     0   14.1  11.2
Name2     France  2019    85.4    25.00   21.5   1     0   17.8  13.9
This is an example where OU and AR are dummy variable and AN, BC, GE, and Lo are percentage. My response variable is 'score' which assumes 0 from 100.
Which family should be more appropriate for glmmTMB?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You could use such a model, but without more information about your data (best would be a reproducible example), it's difficult to give detailed advice.
You may fit your model and check model assumptions, which can be done, e.g. using the performance-package.
There are examples in the vignettes, here how to interpret the diagnostic plots:
https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/check_model.html
Here a case study how to compare different models and figuring out, which model (among several competing models) fits best to the data:
https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/check_model_practical.html

Thank you for your resources:
COMPANY   COUNTRY     YEAR        score    AN         BC          OU     AR    GE      LO
Name1           UK                2018      55.5        33.33     25.4         1        0     22.5     14.1
This is an example where OU and AR are dummy variable and AN, BC, GE, and Lo are percentage.
Maybe could it be better to trascore 'score' by obtaining values from 0 to 1 and use an inverse gaussian?
